# Could a nested loop be replaced with a counter variable to reduce the time complexity?

Tags: java, loops, nested, time-complexity, big-o

This might be a beginner question, but I have a method that is using a nested loop to look for a value inside a 2D array, let's say the body looks something like this: ***(assuming there is always a match for 1 in the 2D array)***

```
        // example array ==> int arr = new int[5][5]
        int length = arr.length;
        int index1 = -1;
        int index2 = -1;

        loop:
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
                if (arr[i][j] == 1) {
                    index1 = i;
                    index2 = j;
                    break loop;
                }
            }
        }
```

I've replaced the second loop with an extra variable **(counter)** in this way:

```
        // example array ==> int arr = new int[5][5]
        int length = arr.length;
        int index1 = -1;
        int index2 = -1;
        int counter = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            if (arr[counter][i] == 1) {
                index1 = counter;
                index2 = i;
                break;
            }

            if (i == length - 1) {
                counter++;
                i = 0;
            }
        }
```

Is this still considered a nested loop with the same time complexity?
And please if there is a good link to understand how to analyze my code complexity in general, attach it!

**This is a sample code, I know that some enhancements could be done, but I'm just asking about the time complexity *(just ignore the edge cases and error handling)***

Comment: The `counter` in your second example will stay `0` forever.

Comment: If you need to iterate over two arrays to find a value at a specific “row”/“column” it doesn’t matter (much) how it’s implemented—you can’t avoid either iteration. You can control when it *stops* iterating but that doesn’t change its O.

Comment: My bad, please check the body again as I forgot to reassign the i and increase the counter correctly.

Comment: How is this not another iteration? The end result is the same (and it’s harder to think about).

Comment: Now it seems that if the array has no 1, the program never ends. And in any case its complexity will still be O(NxM).

Comment: @RealSkeptic I'm mentioned ignoring the edge case, assume there is always a 1 inside it.

Comment: @DaveNewton I'm not saying it's not another iteration, I'm asking if both have the same time complexity or not?

Comment: I doubt there's  a faster solution since it's just a linear search.   If the array is sorted, then you could use binary search.

Comment: @AhmadNasser So if it's another iteration you've kind of answered your own question, no?

Comment: @DaveNewton If I know the answer to my question then why would I even ask it?!
I was asking if there is a time complexity difference between the two examples I provided.

Comment: @AhmadNasser I'm saying that if the end result is two loops how would it alter the time complexity? Regardless of the implementation you're iterating over every elememt of both arrays.

Comment: @DaveNewton That's what my question was about, if the implementation differs, would the complexity still the same, and apparently yes it would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time complexity of your two solutions is the same.

Some people make the mistake of just counting loops. So if there is just one recognizable loop, they'd say this is a linear algorithm. But it isn't, it's still quadratic. What you have to check is how many times the operations that are repeated get repeated.

In this case let's concentrate on the comparison (comparing the array value to 1). It's the most repeated operation (you can verify that yourself) and so the number of time it gets repeated, in proportion to N (the size of one dimension of your array, meaning the array itself is NxN) is what determines the Big O.

So, in your first, two-loop example, each time the inner loop is executed, there are N comparisons. And the inner loop itself is repeated N times because of the outer loop, hence you have NxN comparisons, and you end up with O(N²).

In your second, one-loop example, the comparison is executed as many iterations as the loop. Assuming the worst case scenario, where the 1 is in the last cell, what happens here? Every time you reach the end of a row, you reset the i. So you start counting again from 0 to N-1. So you did N comparisons for `counter = 0`, then N comparisons for `counter = 1` and so on, until `counter` reaches N-1. And so, once again you got NxN comparisons, and therefore O(N²).

So checking loops is just a *rule of thumb*. What you really should be counting is *operations*.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Test App to check the performance for each approach like below code snippet

```java
package test;

public class TestLoops {

    static int numOfItrr = 30000;
    static int[][] arr = new int[numOfItrr][numOfItrr];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        initArr();

        System.out.println("=====================Start======================");
        System.out.println("numOfItrr :" + numOfItrr);
        initArr();
        testWithForLoops();
        testWithCounter();
        System.out.println("=====================Finish=====================");
    }

    public static void initArr() {
        for (int i = 0; i < numOfItrr; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < numOfItrr; j++) {
                arr[i][j] = (int) (Math.random() * 1000);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void testWithForLoops() {
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        int max = arr[0][0];

        for (int i = 0; i < numOfItrr; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < numOfItrr; j++) {
                if (arr[i][j] > max) {
                    max = arr[i][j];
                }
            }
        }

        long end = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("time With loops    = " + (end - start));

    }

    public static void testWithCounter() {
        long start = System.nanoTime();

        int counter = 0;
        int max = arr[0][0];

        for (int i = 0; i < numOfItrr; i++) {
            if (arr[counter][i] > max) {
                max = arr[counter][i];
            }
            if (i == numOfItrr - 1 && counter < numOfItrr - 1) {
                counter++;
                i = 0;
            }
        }

        long end = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("time With Counter  = " + (end - start));
    }

}
```

Here are sample results

====================Start=====================

numOfItrr :10000

time With loops    = 86591300

time With Counter  = 110362600

====================Finish=====================

====================Start=====================

numOfItrr :30000

time With loops    = 754436400

time With Counter  = 978285600

====================Finish=====================

====================Start=====================

numOfItrr :30000

time With loops    = 754230300

time With Counter  = 970180300

====================Finish=====================

Comment: I like the answer and it does show the difference, but is there an explanation for that difference in time?!
they are technically doing the same amount of loops

Comment: As I know no loop is faster than while and basic for loop. As JVM is optimized to run these loops.
https://mkyong.com/java/while-loop-for-loop-and-iterator-performance-test-java/
and from my point of view the time consumed to evaluate this condition 
"if (i == numOfItrr - 1 && counter < numOfItrr - 1)"  consumed the extra time.

Answer (score 0):

You should add this condition to the for loop, or you will have the ArrayOutOfBoundException:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < length && counter < length-1; i++) //if the array is something like new int[5][5]
```

Try to measure the execution time of both with currentTimeMillis(), with different arrays and iterations :)

Comment: I mentioned to please avoid the edge cases just to shorten the question and focus on the main point, as I'm only trying to point out the idea of not using a second for loop.

And there is always a match for 1 in that array.

Answer (score -2):

It considers the content of O() as the maximum number of operations required for execution and 'n' the parameter to identify the size of the input.

The for loop generally iterates over a certain size, which in this case is the size of your array.

A for loop therefore performs at most 'n' operations, which is why it is called linear time or O(n).

In the first case you show two nested for-cycles, in which case a simple multiplication has to be made, because the cycle of complexity O(n) is done at most 'n' times, so it is called quadratic time or O(n^2).

The more the value of O(n) increases, the greater the complexity.

For simplicity:

- For loop is O(n) and It's ok
- 2+ For non-nested loops is O(n+n), but it still says O(n) and It's ok
- 2 For nested loops is O(n*n) and is Not good
- 3 For nested loops is O(n*n*n) and is Really bad

**That is why the second code you sent, assuming there are no errors, is certainly faster than the first.**

Comment: But my main question about the second form, I will end up iterating over the whole array in worst case would that still be considered a O(N^2) or not even tho I'm not specifically writing a second loop?!

Comment: @Eugenio you seem to have taken that graph from [here](https://adrianmejia.com/how-to-find-time-complexity-of-an-algorithm-code-big-o-notation/). Stack Overflow has rules against plagiarism. I would suggest deleting this - and your answer is also unclear and apparently incorrect.

Comment: @AhmadNasser I can write you two nested loops with a runtime complexity of `O(n)`. I can write you a single loop with runtime complexity of `O(n^2)`. It's what happens within those loops that determines the runtime complexity.

Comment: @Turing85 Thank you, that's what I am looking for, that it's not totally about typing a for loop or not!
Could you please refer me to a link to understand more how to analyze my code's time complexity in general?!

Comment: @AhmadNasser [Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, **tutorial or other off-site resource** are **off-topic** for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)